# Unknown PIN preventing me from changing screen lock on Note 4

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note-4

One day, I've noticed that the pattern I always use to unlock my phone and the recovery PIN don't work (never gave it to anyone nor have changed it since I initially put them in). I unlocked it using my Google account, but now the lock screen is stuck to Swipe. I then went to the Screen Lock setting and changed it to PIN, but not only has it not changed from Swipe, but the setting is now protected by a PIN, of which the PIN I used doesn't work.

What do I do now to get rid of that PIN without having to fully reset my phone?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've resolved by this point, but for anyone else that comes across this issue:

I just ran into the same issue on my Galaxy S5.  I managed to resolve it by going to https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager and used the lock option to set a different password.  Then I was able to go into lock screen settings and change to pin/pattern/ect as normal.